# VS2010 Professional using Moles...receive error "System.InvalidOperationException : Could not start Moles host."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, moles

My situation is similar to user2768132's question ([VS2010 pro not able to start Moles host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738251/vs2010-pro-not-able-to-start-moles-host)), however, I have a couple differences.  I also attempted the suggestion by SouthShoreAK but it didn't resolve my problem.  Pardon the similar post.

I'm new to this project at work as well as Moles so I might be missing something simple/obvious.  We are also using Moles framework to write unit test cases but are not able to either debug or run a unit test that involves Moling a public static class.

System - Win-7 Professional SP1
.NET - .NET v4.0.30319 SP1 Rel
VS - VS2010 Professional v10.0.40219.1
Moles - v0.94.51023.0

The solution builds successfully.  The 6 simple unit tests (i.e. not Moling static classes) pass but the one unit test that requires Moles to deal with a static class aborts.

Error for the aborted test:

```
Error   3/26/2014 2:26:06 PM    System.InvalidOperationException: Could not start Moles host. Please review the Test Run Errors for more information.
   at Microsoft.Moles.VsHost.Agent.HostTestAdapterDriver.EnsureHostAdapter()
   at Microsoft.Moles.VsHost.Agent.HostTestAdapterDriver.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.IBaseAdapter.Run(ITestElement testElement, ITestContext testContext)
   at Microsoft.Moles.VsHost.Agent.MolesAgentAdapter.Run(ITestElement testElement, ITestContext testContext)
```

My fuslogvw was empty and did not identify any errors during assembly loading.
I found the same blog as user2768132 that mentioned removing the .exe.config file from privateassemblies folder under VS2010 IDE folder.  I did that and it didn't fix my problem either.

I believe the tests are 32 bit.  With that said, I attempted SouthShoreAK's suggestion of editing the test settings to 64 bit and adding the bitness line to the bottom of the AssemblyInfo.cs file.  Unfortunately, that didn't solve my problem either.  The simple tests that originally passed would fail and the unit test requiring Moles would error saying that Moles cannot be loaded because the key 'Moles' cannot be found.  I undid these changes and I'm back to my starting point.

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to make sure the "Platform target" parameter was set to x86 in the Build tab of the test project's Properties.